# Block matrix notation

Tags: matrices

Given that $A$ is a real, rectangular matrix of dimension $m \times n$ and

$$\begin{align}
A = \left[\begin{array}{c} I \\ e^{\intercal} \\ -e^{\intercal}\end{array}\right]
\end{align}$$

is represented in block matrix notation. What does $A$ look like, given $e$ is a vector of $1$'s?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might look something like this:

$$\left[\begin{array}{cccccc}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
-1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1
\end{array}\right]$$